# Finding address of variable in shared library

Tags: linux, linker, gdb, shared-libraries

I would like to find the address in the .so file of a variable. I do not know the name of if, I only know that it is an integer, and I know the value of it. I also know that once the library is loaded and linked by the dynamic linker the address in the memory is `0x6416A0` relative to the library address. This offset is larger than the size of the dynamic library itself. I only have the binary, compiled version of the library.

To find the address of the variable in the `.so` file I looked at it using `objdump`:

```
$ objdump -x /path/to/lib.so
Program Header:
LOAD off    0x0000000000000000 vaddr 0x0000000000000000 paddr 0x0000000000000000 align 2**21
     filesz 0x0000000000505fa9 memsz 0x0000000000505fa9 flags r-x
LOAD off    0x0000000000506000 vaddr 0x0000000000706000 paddr 0x0000000000706000 align 2**21
     filesz 0x00000000000db8f0 memsz 0x00000000001764c0 flags rw-
DYNAMIC off    0x00000000005210b0 vaddr 0x00000000007210b0 paddr 0x00000000007210b0 align 2**3
     filesz 0x00000000000003e0 memsz 0x00000000000003e0 flags rw-
EH_FRAME off    0x0000000000476898 vaddr 0x0000000000476898 paddr 0x0000000000476898 align 2**2
     filesz 0x0000000000014674 memsz 0x0000000000014674 flags r--
STACK off    0x0000000000000000 vaddr 0x0000000000000000 paddr 0x0000000000000000 align 2**3
     filesz 0x0000000000000000 memsz 0x0000000000000000 flags rw-
[...]
```

Above I only showed the `Program Header`, but the address I am looking for is not in any address range of the available sections. As you see, addresses used are as large as `0x7210b0`, but my address is not in any of the ranges I see.

Since the linker uses `mmap` to load the contents of the `.so` file, I assumed that knowing the offset in the memory is equivalent to knowing the offset in the file. Apparently this is wrong. Could anyone help me understand how that works? Is there a simple way to map the memory address onto the file address?

Comment: If you don't even know what the variable is called, then you're going to have a bit of a job finding it. It's kind of like saying "There is this thing and I want to find it. It's red, but I don't know what it's called. Can you help me find it?". In all seriousness, can't you just build and link the library again with adjustments? Why is it you want to find where this is in the library anyway?

Comment: @Phil_12d3 Of course I can not build and link it - some libraries come in binary. The question is not about finding _something red_: I do know the address of the variable after linking, in the memory. What I do not know is how the linker actually loads the library, and which physical part of the file does the address map onto.

Comment: @angainor sorry, but you didn't say you couldn't - it was just an idea. I have loads of libraries and also have the code for them too. `nm` is unlikely to help either, since it will show the address, section and name only. You may be able to take an educated guess though with what it could be.

Comment: Output of `cat /proc/<pid>/maps` ?

Comment: @ninjalj Bingo - that did help me get what I want. The dynamic library was mmaped multiple times, one of the memory ranges did contain the address I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on a Linux system with a [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), and if the variable is a known name inside the dynamic symbol table of some [dynamically linked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) library, i.e. [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) shared object, and if you can change the code of the main program (or some shared object dynamically linked by it, perhaps playing `LD_PRELOAD` tricks) you could use the [dladdr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dladdr.3.html) function (given a pointer, `dladdr` gives you a `Dl_info` structure with symbol and shared object names close to the given pointer).

Since dynamically linked shared object libraries are often [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)-ed at non predictable addresses (e.g. because of [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR)) you need to do that at runtime. (See also `/proc/self/maps` from inside your process; read [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) etc...)

Read [Drepper's paper: *How to write Shared Libraries*](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf); be aware of [VDSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDSO)...

Notice that a given `*.so` file has several `mmap`-ed segments, and that some of its (file) data is *not* `mmap`-ed! Use [pmap(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html) to find out.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I do not know the name of the variable. However, your answer and the comment of @ninjalj did let me solve the problem. In `/proc/self/maps` I see that the library is mmaped multiple times, with a different offset into the .so file. One of the virtual address ranges listed there did contain the variable address I was looking for, and so I was able to find the corresponding address in the .so file. Brilliant! Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to know the name of the variable. `dladdr` would find it. You definitely should read Drepper's (long) paper!

Comment: True, I see it now. But in my case the variable does not seem to be exported (local?). I will play again with `dladdr`, but since I now know the file address, I see that it is not listed next to any exported symbol shown by `objdump -T`. So I guess `dladdr` would also not find it. Am I right?