# How to find virtual address of variable in OPENSSL shared library

Tags: c, linux, gcc, assembly

I am using shared library of openssl.

Inside bn_exp.c file, BN_mod_exp_mont function is defined, which declare a pointer variable of type BIGNUM,  **BIGNUM *val[TABLE_SIZE].**

BN_mod_exp_mont function calls BN_mod_mul_montgomery function (defined inside bn_mont.c file)  and **pass address of BIGNUM val** to that function.

BN_mod_mul_montgomery function calls  BN_mul function defined inside bn_mul.c file. It also pass address of val while calling 
BN_mul function.

Finally, **BN_mul function access address of val to perform multiplication** .

Here is my questions :

1. **How to find Memory Address (Virtual address) of val , defined inside shared library of openssl (BN_mod_exp_mont function) without making any changes inside OPENSSL.** (I was reading this [Finding address of variable in shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236263/finding-address-of-variable-in-shared-library) , but unable to understand how to use)
2. Due to size of BIGNUM, this variable won't be stored inside a register. It will be stored in Main memory only, not in register. AM I right?
3. Is it possible, to find address of a variable defined inside a function with respect to its activation record during runtime?

Here is the function defined inside openssl.

```
// File : bn_exp.c 

int BN_mod_exp_mont(BIGNUM *rr, const BIGNUM *a, const BIGNUM *p,
            const BIGNUM *m, BN_CTX *ctx, BN_MONT_CTX *in_mont)
    {
    int i,j,bits,ret=0,wstart,wend,window,wvalue;
    int start=1;
    BIGNUM *d,*r;
    const BIGNUM *aa;
    /* Table of variables obtained from 'ctx' */
    BIGNUM *val[TABLE_SIZE];

    BN_CTX_start(ctx);
    d = BN_CTX_get(ctx);
    r = BN_CTX_get(ctx);
    val[0] = BN_CTX_get(ctx);

    if (!d || !r || !val[0]) goto err;

    .
    .
    .
    .

    // Initialize val[0]

    if (!BN_to_montgomery(val[0],aa,mont,ctx)) goto err; /* 1 */

    window = BN_window_bits_for_exponent_size(bits);
    if (window > 1)
        {
        if (!BN_mod_mul_montgomery(d,val[0],val[0],mont,ctx)) goto err; /* 2 */
        j=1<<(window-1);
        for (i=1; i<j; i++)
            {

            // Initialize Val[1] --- val[7]
            if(((val[i] = BN_CTX_get(ctx)) == NULL) ||  !BN_mod_mul_montgomery(val[i],val[i-1], d,mont,ctx))
                goto err;
            }
        }



    .
    .
    .
    .
    .

    // Use of val[0] | val[1] | val[2] ....

    for(i=0;i<60;i++) // This shows that val is stored in stack till function expires
    if (!BN_mod_mul_montgomery(r,r,val[wvalue>>1],mont,ctx))
            goto err;


err :

    .
    . 
}



// File : bn_mont.c. Passing address of val as variable const BIGNUM *b.

int BN_mod_mul_montgomery(BIGNUM *r, const BIGNUM *a, const BIGNUM *b,
              BN_MONT_CTX *mont, BN_CTX *ctx)
    {
    BIGNUM *tmp;
    int ret=0;

    BN_CTX_start(ctx);
    tmp = BN_CTX_get(ctx);
    .
    .
    . 

    if (!BN_mul(tmp,a,b,ctx)) goto err;

}
```

I am using gcc under linux ubuntu. Thanks in advance .

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What is the background to this?

Comment: `val` is a local variable that exists on the stack only for the lifetime of a single call to `BN_mod_exp_mont`. So there's no way to get at its address unless you can control the process while this function is running (using a debugger, for example).

Comment: @nwellnhof , I have updated the program where val is used for around 50-60 times. So during that time val will be inside stack . Can I write a c program or inline assembly to find address of val ?

Comment: @bholanath, can you change callee code to analyse caller stack frame? AFAIC it is inside openssl too. Or you are interesting in how to use gdb?

Comment: @KonstantinVladimirov I can't change callee code also as it is inside openssl. I want to write another program where before calling BN_mod_exp_mont, which will indirectly call BN_mod_mul_montgomery / BN_mul, try to find the virtual address of val. I tried to use gdb, I found the address of val[0] with respect to ebp, but unable to understand how to use that info to find virtual address of val from other program where I am calling BN_mod_exp_mont/BN_mod_mul_montgomery ?

Comment: @bholanath don't you realize, that this variable doesn't exists anywhere before BN_mod_exp_mont actually called? This is just a part of runtime stack, it have no *constant* location. Still when you are inside its callee, you might think about caller's frame as something constant for your lifetime. Ok, I got, it is not your case.

Comment: @KonstantinVladimirov, I am actually looking answer for your comment - "when you are inside its callee (BN_mod_mul_montgomery/BN_mul), you might think about caller's frame as something constant for your lifetime". Is there any way to find address of val , when program executing inside BN_mul function?

Comment: There is. But determining code should be written inside callee. Which is not your case.

Comment: @KonstantinVladimirov, how can I do that "determining code should be written inside callee" ? Is it like adding some other variable and declared as extern and accessing that address ? I may first try that and later think other way to do without writing code inside callee .

Comment: @bholanath simply use ``__builtin_frame_address`` inside callee to determine caller's frame and subtract appropriate number of bytes for offset from frame start

Comment: @KonstantinVladimirov, thanks . will try this way and let you know .